# Meaning of .IsA in Python

Tags: c++, python

I have some problems when trying to translate Python to C++. One of them is .IsA .
What does it really mean? I have searched it on Python doc, but there is no result.

Moreover, how can I translate it into C++?

My code in Python is:

```
if volumeNode.IsA("vtkMRMLDiffusionTensorVolumeNode"):
```

Comment: What made you think that it is a part of the language, and not some member function of whatever-class-volumeNode-is?

Comment: ^About to say the same thing.

Comment: Since it looks a little bit different for vtk in Python and C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a method of `vtkMRMLNode` that tells you if an object is an instance of the class with the given name.

The docs are [here](http://slicer.org/doc/html/classvtkMRMLNode.html#ad0ae2f08b6690ac0ead16addcf38bd98).

Your C++ code would look like

```
if (volumeNode->IsA("vtkMRMLDiffusionTensorVolumeNode"))
```

Comment: but in what way a vtkMRMLVolumeNode will be an instance of vtkMRMLDiffusionTensorVolumeNode ?

Comment: @ManLokHui It's a base class, just like in Python (the Python API is a wrapper around the C++ API).

Answer (score 0):

I think `IsA` is not a keyword, a built-in function or anything. It's a method of a class instance `volumeNode`.